# In a Virtual Machine, is the Virtual Processor using RAM or part of the Processor?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I am running a 15" MacBook Pro (2.66GHz) and 4GB of RAM. I am considering downgrading to a 13 MacBook Pro (2.4GHz) with 8GB of RAM.

Most of what I do at work is through Windows and I need to run it virtually. So my real question is when running a virtual machine will the virtual processor be utilizing RAM or part of the hosts processor?

My assumption is that it will utilize the allocated RAM but I have seen zero documentation to support that.

Answer (score 4):

The virtual machine uses both physical RAM and physical *CPU Time*.

Comment: As a comment, if the OP by some reason will install a 32-bit version of Windows, it will use no more than 4GB of RAM total and 3GB would be only accessible for applications.

Comment: No, the collection of all applications could use almost all 4 GB of RAM. The "3 GB limit" you're thinking of (2 GB by default) is for the _per process_ virtual address space, not physical (RAM) usage by all processes.